# Show that $\int_0^1 f^3(x) dx + \frac{4}{27} \ge \left( \int_0^1 f(x) dx \right)^2$, where $f',f'' >0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

> Let $f :[0,1] \to [0,\infty)$, $f$ is twice differentiable, $f'(x) >0$, $f''(x) >0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Prove that
> $$ \int_0^1 f^3(x) dx + \frac{4}{27} \ge \left( \int_0^1 f(x) dx \right)^2.$$
> Here $f^3(x)$ power means $f(x)$ raised to power $3$.

I got this problem from our WhatsApp preparation group for math exams from my friend who tried this without success.

My ideas : I had very less ideas about the problem but I did try to use Mean Value theorems without success. Observe that $4$ is a square which is somehow related to the RHS portion of the inequality and $27$ is cube which is somehow might be related to LHS first term. I also observed the fact $f$ is a convex function.

Any help in this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: +1 Interesting question, OP showed reasonable work trying to solve problem, graphics were legible, and OP provided backround re WhatsApp preparation group.  Minor editing suggestion: Re formatting math at mathSE, please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: There are several good reasons to post questions as text, not as an image. See for example https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11697/42969.

Comment: @MartinR I absolutely agree with you, out of hand.  In this case, I tried to shape my *criticism* with a light touch, because the graphics were **at least** legible, and with respect to the OP's showing work + background, his query was (in my opinion) better than 90% of the queries posted on mathSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Holder inequality,
$$\left(\int_0^1 f(x) dx\right)^2 \le \left(\int_0^1 f^3(x) dx\right)^{2/3}$$
then by Young's

\begin{align}\left(\int_0^1 f^3(x) dx\right)^{2/3}&= \left(\frac 32 \int_0^1 f^3(x) dx\right)^{2/3}\left( \frac 23\right)^{2/3}\\
&\le \int_0^1 f^3(x) dx + (2/3)^2/3 = \int_0^1 f^3(x) dx + \frac{4}{27}
\end{align}

The conditions on $f', f''$ are not used.

Comment: Just mentioning that the inequality is sharp: Equality holds for the constant function $f(x) = 2/3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx=t$.

Thus, by Holder and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\int\limits_0^1f(x)^3dx+\frac{4}{27}=\left(\int\limits_0^11dx\right)^2\int\limits_0^1f(x)^3dx+\frac{4}{27}\geq\left(\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx\right)^3+\frac{4}{27}=$$
$$=t^3+\frac{4}{27}=2\cdot\frac{t^3}{2}+\frac{4}{27}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{t^3}{2}\right)^2\cdot\frac{4}{27}}=t^2=\left(\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx\right)^2.$$